# Angular запускает функцию fireUrlChange()

Tags: angularjs

Доброго времени суток.
Помогите пожалуйста, есть огромный SPA использующий старую версию angular 1.4.8

По всему проекту, для перехода между "страницами" используется функция ToUrl с таким вот кодом:

```js
var ToUrl = function (relativeUrl) {
        var mainContainerElement = window.angular.element("#MainContainer")
        var rootScope = mainContainerElement.injector().get("$rootScope");
        var ngLocation = rootScope.ngLocation;
        
        if (rootScope && ngLocation) {
            rootScope.historyPushCount = 1;
            rootScope.$evalAsync(ngLocation.url(relativeUrl));
        }
    }
};
```

Во всех местах, где эта функция(ToUrl) вызывается все нормально. Кроме одного сервиса. Почему-то angular отправляет еще один запрос к серверу с тем же url, на который осуществляется переход функцией ToUrl. Получается 2 запроса подряд.

С помощью отладчика нашел функцию fireUrlChange, в которой есть проверка lastHistoryState === cachedState и эта проверка возвращает false. Из за этого angular создает еще один запрос. В ременной cachedState всегда null, но на время срабатывания функции там почему-то оказывается цифра 2.

Вот код функции fireUrlChange:

```js
function fireUrlChange() {
 if (lastBrowserUrl === self.url() && lastHistoryState === cachedState) {
  return;
 }
     
 lastBrowserUrl = self.url();
 lastHistoryState = cachedState;
 forEach(urlChangeListeners, function(listener) {
    listener(self.url(), cachedState);
 });
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста, как найти причину изменения параметра cachedState (или lastHistoryState)?

Comment: Описанное вами поведение очень похоже на принудительное добавление хеша в ссылку после выполнения перехода на страницу. Обычно подобные "трюки" выполняют для позиционирования на на указанном якоре в странице.

Comment: Вызов fireUrlChange с двойкой в состоянии это нормальное поведение ангуляра и подобный вызов не должен перезагружать страницу. Возможно проблема в том что где то в коде слишком рано меняется состояние $browser.state

Comment: @Nikolay, не могли бы вы скинуть какую-то подробную информацию как этот fireUrlChange работает? Нигде не могу ничего откопать, а по коду общей картины не понимаю :(

Comment: подробной документации предоставить не могу, т.к. никогда не встречал подобной. Моё утверждение основано на чтении исходников самого ангуляра.